# Bluetooth Reconnect Audio Issues

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio, drivers, bluetooth

I've recently bought TaoTronics TT-BH07 Bluetooth Headphones to use with my Vaio laptop (model:SVE14A190X) with Windows 7 64-bit. This laptop has an integrated Bluetooth Radio Adapter with the model Atheros AR3012. Initial setup of pairing the earphones to laptop works perfectly fine. Here's some brief specifications on my laptop.

```
       Machine name: VAIO
   Operating System: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1 (7601.win7sp1_ldr.161011-0600)
           Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: Sony Corporation
       System Model: SVE14A190X
               BIOS: BIOS Date: 12/17/15 08:56:51 Ver: 04.06.05
          Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3612QM CPU @ 2.10GHz (8 CPUs), ~2.1GHz
             Memory: 8192MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 8088MB RAM
          Page File: 6070MB used, 10105MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\Windows
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.01.7601.17514 64bit Unicode
```

I also have complete hardware specifications done by CPU-Z here:
http://pastebin.com/qUURfy43

To get straight to the point, the problem is as follows:

1. I turn on the earphones which automatically pairs it to the laptop.
2. At this point, the audio is perfectly fine. All sounds work in good quality. As long as sound is continuously playing, the audio does not have any issues.
3. After not having any audio output for several seconds to few minutes, I presume that the earphones go on standby to save battery.
   4). Playing audio after earphones go on standby have all audio be chopped off and stutters.

Here are things that I have done from Googling for past few days:

1. I have set my Bluetooth Earphones as my default device.
2. I have disabled Handsfree Telephony on the Bluetooth Services.
3. I have selected "Do nothing" on Communications tab under Sounds.
4. I have tried reinstalling my Bluetooth drivers.
5. I have tried updating my Bluetooth drivers. Unfortunately, I downgraded after giving this a shot, due to laptop-specific driver incompatibility (Bluetooth Peripheral Device was not installing and there were no generic Bluetooth driver certificate signing for me). However, the Bluetooth still worked fine, albeit same problems as before. It made no difference.
6. I have tried going to Power Management tab under my Bluetooth devices to deselect the option for computer to "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power." The problem with this is that there's no said Power Management tab under my Bluetooth adapter, as it's not an external dongle. It's listed under Bluetooth Radios instead of just "Bluetooth."
7. I used DPC Latency Checker to see if it was the problem with the hardware. Averaging at 100 μs, there were no problems.
8. I tried turning on sound enhancements off, including the Dolby theater mode that it seems to come with for sound ambience.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I wish to say that is the case, but connecting to the phone has absolutely no issues and works perfectly, and this earphones are brand new. The drivers, albeit laptop-specific as mentioned before, are outdated, as the laptop was bought quite some time ago (roughly 4~5 years).

Comment: Can you try it on a newer laptop with more up to date drivers? Alternatively you may need to buy a newer Bluetooth dongle that supports the newer standards

Comment: I have tried it on a new laptop with your suggestion, and there do not seem to be any problems. Buying a newer Bluetooth dongle is my absolute last resort, since I do not really wish to spend more money, but I will if there's no other choice.